# MySQL Host in Django/Nginx/Python setup - reverts to localhost

Tags: python, mysql, django, nginx, passenger

Odd issue here. This setup used to work in the past on our Django / Nginx / Python setup but is causing issues on a new machine.

Very standard settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dev_database',
        'USER': 'dev_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'devuser',
        'HOST': '123.123.123.123',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

In the past, not a problem connecting to that HOST (123.123.123.123) however now Django reports that it's attempting to connect to the localhost (let's call that 192.0.0.1):

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'dev_user'@'192.0.0.1' (using password: YES)")
```

We've flushed settings, wiped out `.pyc` files, double checked settings.

Answer (score 0):

I hate myself. The password had yet to be set on the RDS db so it was returning that error. Carry on, Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have the same problem, any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You'll need to set/reset the password for that account on your database. Verify that the credentials you're using to connect to your DB are fully operational, we neglected to do so. A terrible assumption to make.